# Material-UI: Code not working after updating the library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am fairly new to material-ui and have been having trouble making my code work, once i updated from 0.14.4 to 0.15.4 . 
Following is a snippet of my code:

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  LoginDialog = require('./login-dialog.jsx'),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton,
  MuiThemeProvider = require('material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider');



var Index = React.createClass({


  //childContextTypes: {
  //  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  //},
  //
  //getChildContext: function() {
  //  return {
  //    muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
  //  };
  //},

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mui-app-canvas home-page-background">
        <RaisedButton
          className="login-button"
          label="Login"
          onTouchTap={ this._handleLoginDialog }
          linkButton={ false } />
        <LoginDialog
          ref="loginDialog"
          loginUrl={ this.props.loginUrl } />
      </div>
    )
  },

  _handleLoginDialog: function() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.show();
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

The error i am getting is

> TypeError: this.context.muiTheme is undefined

I have looked into using MuithemeProvider and wrapping my code, the way its showed in documentation :

http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage

But i am getting a different error. Any help would be appreciated.

After discussing following is the solution

Material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme.js is transpiled from an ES2015 source, and the function is exported as a default.

Edited Code after discussion with @activatedgeek and @robertkelp

---

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  LoginDialog = require('./login-dialog.jsx'),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton,
  MuiThemeProvider = require('material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'),
  getMuiTheme = require('material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme').default,
  darkBaseTheme = require('material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme');



var Index = React.createClass({
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)
    };
  },

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mui-app-canvas home-page-background">
        <RaisedButton
          className="login-button"
          label="Login"
          onTouchTap={ this._handleLoginDialog }
          linkButton={ false } />
        <LoginDialog
          ref="loginDialog"
          loginUrl={ this.props.loginUrl } />
      </div>
    )
  },

  _handleLoginDialog: function() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.show();
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base component `BaseMUI.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';

/**
 * Basic theme bookkeeping for Material UI
 */
class BaseMUI extends React.Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)
    };
  }
}

BaseMUI.childContextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default BaseMUI;
```

Now every new component you create, use the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import BaseMUI from './BaseMUI';

class MyComponent extends BaseMUI {
  // you component code here
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**NOTE**: If you don't want to create an extra component, you need to include the `getChildContext` method in every component where you use `Material-UI` components.

Comment: Hey, Thanks !. Is there way not to use darkBaseTheme as i wanted to use inline styles. Also how to make it work in standard javascript without using the extra component . Thanks again.

Comment: @AdityaPatel Yes, just override the styles when you create your component (but you do need to use a base style which is very helpful in many cases). You can also create your own theme file if you wish. Without an extra component, as I mentioned, just copy `getChildContext ` into your component. Please mark the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried the change, got an error: getMuiTheme is not a function

Comment: @AdityaPatel You need to import appropriate library of course. See the code above.

Comment: i have added the libraries as you can see the answer in the above question. Please let me know what else might be happening . Thanks so much for replying patiently.

Comment: What do you mean? You still haven't got it working? If not, then please specify that in your question properly.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not working, i had added the code so far which i have written. I will make the edit in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121911/discussion-between-aditya-patel-and-activatedgeek).